# Anchor hover remain the same after click the link

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover

Suppose I want create nav-top-menu buttons, each button has anchor tag and href is given. I had style a:hover to each button. When I click through the link, the a:hover to that button I click was gone.I want the anchor hover remain the same after I click the link. It is better I did this in CSS.

```
button a:hover {
border:1px solid #000;
box-shadow:1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
button a:hover {
    border:1px solid #000;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
    }
button a:active
{
        border:1px solid #000;
        box-shadow:1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax in your CSS code. **Here is the right solution:**

```
a.button:hover {
border:1px solid #000;
box-shadow:1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
}

a.button:active {
border:1px solid #000;
box-shadow:1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
}
```

The class of the `<a>` is `button`.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you've used the selector:

```
button a:hover
```

This is almost certainly not the selector you need to use, this selects an  element inside a  element in its hover state. You might have your .button class on the actual link and then select them with:

a.button:hover

this selects an element  in it's hover state.

Back to your main question, to style the link in its "active" or after it has been "activated", you need to use the :active [pseudo-class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aactive). You should also use the :focus selector so that people using just the keyboard will see your style change too.

```
a.button:hover,
a.button:focus,
a.button:active {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
}
```

Here I've chained all the selectors together to save you repeating the styles. You could also do it without the "a" element selector in there (depending on your other css):

```
.button:hover,
.button:focus,
.button:active {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px 8px #1fb6dc;
}
```

If it works this way, it will make you're css a bit more flexible (see [object oriented css](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)).